# Google sheet script to add a week to a date from the sheet

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

Sorry - I'm a newbie!

I need to use a script to read a date from a Googlesheet, add a week and save the new date back to the sheet.

I've tried various suggestions from various posts without success.  The approach I thought should work is failing to get a millisecond value from a date from a cell - subsequent processing appeared OK.

```
var oldDate  = sheet.getRange('oldDateRange').getValue(); // obtains a date object and then...
var oldDateValue = oldDate.getMilliseconds() // I expected to return milliseconds but shows as undefined...
```

See [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SENO1D-ucUH5LU7BZN6XellHf9Rlw03iDHI-oSZiCHY/edit?usp=sharing) to a simplified illustration sheet and script illustrating my problem.

This is my first question on StackOverflow - feedback welcome on how to make it more helpful for others....

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.  You can also check [ask] for more tips on writing questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert the date obtained from the sheet to milliseconds, I think you simply need to replace `.getMilliseconds()` with `.getTime()`

Comment: Many thanks for an excellent nudge in the right direction!  That produced milliseconds, and to get the date back on the sheet I also had to create a new Date object using the calculated ms value.  I've edited the linked sheet with the working solution.